# ML algorithm to find optimal control parameter

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, cart

I have a training dataset $(X, y) \rightarrow z$. Where $X$ is an $n$th dimensional real vector, $y$ is an integer number in $\{1, 2, 3\}$, and $z$ is a real number. I am looking for machine learning algorithm which solves the next problem: $X$ is given and we need to choose $y$ for maximization $z$. I would prefer if it would be something like decision trees.
I would really appreciate some advice on that.

Comment: Are you looking for code? Or are you asking which algorithm is best (because that is a difficult answer)? Basically any supervised learning algorithm will give you an answer

Comment: No, I'm not looking for code. Are you suggesting to teach some prediction algorithm $f(X, y) = z$ and maximize $f(X,y)$ over $\{1,2,3\}$? There is problem for me: when I teach decision tree I have to use small depths to avoid overfitting and dependence from $y$ disappears =(.